# Django - turn field into tags with dropdown

Tags: python, html, css, django, tags

In my form on django, I have a field called package_includes and a field called price. Right now, the content in package_includes it is simply text. So if I input "paper, glue, glitter" it will display exactly as i typed it, unable to change anything. However, I want the text to work like individual tags ->[How I want tags to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbHLs.png)

So when you click on one of the individual items (EX: "paper", "glue", or "glitter") i want it to display a drop down that allows you the option to put extra glitter for an additional $2.00 to the total.

Also, at the end of the text I want a tag that displays "Add" and this function would allow you to add items not included in this specific package. For example, you should be able to add crayons for $5, highlighter for $2.50, etc.

I am new to programming and don't fully understand how to add a function to text like this in a field in django. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You cannot do it with pure Django. You can use external UI library with all the required components or write your own js. As far as you are new to programming I recommend the first option. Have a look, for instance, at http://semantic-ui.com/elements/label.html. Anyway, I think the question is to broad and can have many good answers

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is unfortunately not a step-by-step instruction of how to go from 0 to a complete working example - only a pointer in the right direction.

What you need is achieved through CSS (producing the visual effect you want) and JavaScript (handling the drop-down functionality; it most probably has to be your own script based on jQuery). All of what you want needs to live (execute) within the Internet browser, and Django can only help there by serving the static CSS and script files, and referencing them in the actual page, when you put them in the correct template.

Here is an example of Wagtail Admin doing something similar:

[image: Example of Taggit tags in Django Wagtail Admin]

If you open the page source in your browser, all you will see as HTML code for this is the following:

```html
<div class="field-content">
    <div class="input  ">
            <input id="id_tags" name="tags" type="text" value="&quot;hello world&quot;, blog" /><script>initTagField("id_tags", "/admin/tag-autocomplete/");</script>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But if you open the page with FireBug, your browser's Development Tools, or the Web Developer extension, with visual styles applied it will decompose to something like this:

[image: Taggit tags in Django Wagtail Admin displayed in Chrome Developer Tools]

If you notice, the applied style to the form input element is `display: none;`. What you see is actually the styled unordered list elements right after. In order to be able to use them in your script, you need to be able to get to them/their contents from within your JS function. One strategy would be to assign an id attribute to all of the visible `<li>` elements. It can be something counter-based (e.g. `id="shopping-cart-item-0"`, `id="shopping-cart-item-1"`, etc.). Another way would be to assign an id to the `<div class="input">` element, and within your function get all its DOM descendants of type `<li>`. Whatever works better for you. Then you could parse the label (inner text) of the list element in your script to get the type of item you are dealing with, and from then on find the discount price and apply it...

I would suggest that you start with a working example - find some app that uses taggit or similar package for Django and install it in a test application. Then you can use your browser's or preferred web development extension to play around with the CSS on them and see how different options affect the visual aspect of what you need. Once you are comfortable with that, see how you can build drop-down menus with jQuery. I believe the jQuery site has enough tutorials on the topic.